# Code for Degrees not

Tags: arduino-nano, stepper

Using Audrino Nano and MKS SERVO42 42 Stepper Motor With Driver Board Closed Loop with the LCD. I have got the motor going by using the menu on board. Now able to run Code1 https://github.com/makertut/Arduino-Closed-loop.git out of GitHub and it runs as it is designed. Line 5 int numstep = 1030; cc runs the number of steps indicated and changing this number will determine the movement.
I can do the math to calculate the degrees for number of step for a particular stepper. I would like to use degrees instead of steps for my program. Does anybody know how to code this?
Thanks Greg

Comment: convert the angle to step count

Comment: You can find the number of steps per revolution in the specification of the stepper motor. Then just calculate the angle from the steps. Simple rule of three

Comment: If you can calculate the number of steps per degree you can calculate the number of degrees per step. It's high school math. Not even high school math. It's bordering on preschool math...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I said I could do the math in my question. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question or didn't supply enough info. I going to monitor multiple sensors, When one sensor is detected I want the stepper to turn to a certain degree such as 45, If another, different sensor is detected it would move to that place say 90.  Every sensor would be assign a specific degree or position.  Will steps act the same as degrees?  If  the stepper is at 90 degrees (or 50 steps) and the first sensor is then detected will it move to the 45 degree position (or 25 steps) position.   360/1.8=200

Answer (score 1):

This is basic algebra 1.

Say `steps / degree = 5`

So write that as 2 fractions:

```
steps   5
----- = -
degree  1
```

Then take the reciprocal of both sides:

```
degrees   1
------- = -
step      5
```